Storm UI cannot find Nimbus
I am using a docker compose to spin up a number of items, including Nimbus, and storm. While everything is up and running from the docker desktop, when I try to access the UI, it shows org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException.
Here is the docker compose file
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"

  solr:
    image: solr:latest
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      SOLR_HOME: /opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    volumes:
      - ./solrdata:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores

  storm-nimbus:
    image: storm:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - NIMBUS_SEEDS=["storm-nimbus"]
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS=["zookeeper"]
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181
    command: storm nimbus
    ports:
      - "6627:6627"  # Nimbus port

  storm-supervisor:
    image: storm:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - storm-nimbus
    environment:
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS=["zookeeper"]
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181
      - NIMBUS_SEEDS=["storm-nimbus"]
    command: storm supervisor

  storm-ui:
    image: storm:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - storm-nimbus
    environment:
      - NIMBUS_SEEDS=["storm-nimbus"]
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS=["zookeeper"]
      - STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT=2181
    command: storm ui
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  # Storm UI port

  hazelcast:
    image: hazelcast/hazelcast:latest
    ports:
      - "5701:5701"
    environment:
      HZ_CLUSTER_NAME: dev
    volumes:
      - ./hazelcast-data:/data

After running docker compose up -d it looks like everything is running.

Hoever checking on http://localhost:8080 we find the following:

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.
